# Fixed Format Output w/ Column Data of Various Lengths

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

XSLT v 1.0
Source XML

```
    <Vehicle>
       <Parts>
         <Part SN="1234567" PartNumber="223232" Build="2W345" Manuf="K3E4" Mater="12312">
           <Inspections ManufI="K3F4"/> 
           <Recalls  ID="1223-4" Status="02"/>
           <Recalls  ID="1987-9" Status="07" />
           <Recalls ID="1211-10" Status="17" />
           <Recalls ID="4545-1" Status="07" />
           <Recalls ID="2291-7" Status="01" />
           <Recalls ID="2322-4" Status="04" />
         </Part>
         <Part SN="1255" PartNumber="87666" Build="3ED55" Manuf="98772" Mater="8YT76">
           <Inspections /> 
           <Recalls  ID="5676-4" Status="01"/>
           <Recalls  ID="13347-9" Status="01" /> 
             <Part> SN="1256" PartNumber="76554" Build="3R453" Manuf="7U7Yt" 
                                    Mater="9I123">
              <Inspections />
              <Recalls />
             </Part>
         </Part>
    </Parts>
    </Vehicle>
```

I'm trying to produce the following fixed format file.  The 'recalls' list is just a list of recalls for the serial number (SN) it has no relationship to the Type and Code columns to its left.  As the sample demonstrates it may be longer or shorter than the list of type and codes.

```
SN          PartNumber  Type    Code         Recall     Status
1234567     223232      Manuf   K3E4         1223-4     02
                        ManufI  K3F4         1987-9     07
                        Mater   12312        1211-10    17
                        Build   2W345        4545-1     07
                                             2291-7     01
                                             2322-4     01

1255        87666       Manuf   98772        5676-4     01
                        Mater   8YT76        13347-9    01
                        Build   3ED55    

1256        76554       Manuf   7U7Yt
                        Mater   9I123
                        Build   3R453
```

Comment: You seem to have 2 separate questions here: (1) how to produce independent columns of data and (2) how to generate a fixed-with text file. Which one of these are you having the problem with? -- Also, which XSLT 1.0 processor will you be using?

Comment: Independent columns is my issue.  The code I'm trying to port from was older .NET but now using .NET 4.6.1 so in researching your processor question looks like I might be able to move to XSLT 2.0

Comment: I suggest you find out for sure, because it makes a difference for both questions. In a nutshell, if you create a node-set (or a sequence, in XSLT 2.0) of each column values, you can then loop and create each row in turn until all columns have run out.

Comment: I'll be able to get there from that example. One followup...  How would I have to change the outer template if I encounter nested parts.  `<Parent><Parts><Part SN='11111'><Part SN='2222' /></Part></Parts></Parent>

Comment: I don't know how to answer that without seeing an example of the input and the expected output. Of course, if ALL parts are nested, then it is trivial to change `<xsl:for-each select="Parts/Part">` to `<xsl:for-each select="Parts/Part/Part">`.

Comment: Parts/child parts may have varying level of nesting but the output is expected to be a flattened list without indication of the nested nature of the source.  I've amended the original to reflect this.  Thanks

Comment: You could use `<xsl:for-each select="//Part">`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example you could use as your starting point. For simplicity, it generates a CSV output rather than a fixed-width file.

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/Vehicle">
    <xsl:text>SN, PartNumber, Type, Code, Recall, Status&#10;</xsl:text>    
    <xsl:for-each select="Parts/Part">
        <xsl:call-template name="generate-rows">
            <xsl:with-param name="types" select="@Manuf | @Build | @Mater | Inspections/@ManufI" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="generate-rows">
    <xsl:param name="types"/>
    <xsl:param name="i" select="1"/>
    <!-- part columns -->
    <xsl:value-of select="@SN[$i]"/>
    <xsl:text>, </xsl:text> 
    <xsl:value-of select="@PartNumber[$i]"/>
    <xsl:text>, </xsl:text> 
    <!-- type columns -->
    <xsl:value-of select="name($types[$i])"/>
    <xsl:text>, </xsl:text> 
    <xsl:value-of select="$types[$i]"/>
    <xsl:text>, </xsl:text> 
    <!-- recall columns -->
    <xsl:value-of select="Recalls[$i]/@ID"/>
    <xsl:text>, </xsl:text> 
    <xsl:value-of select="Recalls[$i]/@Status"/>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    <!-- recursive call -->
    <xsl:if test="$i &lt; count($types) or $i &lt; count(Recalls)">
        <xsl:call-template name="generate-rows">
            <xsl:with-param name="types" select="$types"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="i" select="$i + 1"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your input example, this will produce:

**Result**

```
SN, PartNumber, Type, Code, Recall, Status
1234567, 223232, Build, 2W345, 1223-4, 02
, , Manuf, K3E4, 1987-9, 07
, , Mater, 12312, 1211-10, 17
, , ManufI, K3F4, 4545-1, 07
, , , , 2291-7, 01
, , , , 2322-4, 04
1255, 87666, Build, 3ED55, 5676-4, 01
, , Manuf, 98772, 13347-9, 01
, , Mater, 8YT76, ,
```

which corresponds to:

[image]